# how to check if a image will load or not in JS

Tags: javascript

I am making a news website with news API for practice and sometimes some images do not load. So how can I set a logical condition like ***"use this image if this does not load"***.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this...
Replace the `invalid_link` and `https://placeimg.com/200/300/animals` with your links.

```html
<img src="invalid_link" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='https://placeimg.com/200/300/animals';">
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how you're handling the images - are they hardcoded in the HTML, are they in an array?

This example uses a [Promise-based](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) method to replace all bad images with dummy images.

An array of image objects (name, src), is [`mapped`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over. For each iteration (for each object) it calls `checkIfImageExists` with the src, and based on what the function returns (either true or false) returns either the original object (true) or a new object with the dummy image as the src.

When you run the snippet you will see that `badImage` (2nd object) has had the src replaced with the dummy image URI.

```js
function checkIfImageExists(src) {

  return new Promise(res => {

    const img = new Image();

    img.src = src;

    if (img.complete) {
      res(true);
    } else {

      img.onload = () => {
        res(true);
      };

      img.onerror = () => {
        res(false);
      };

    }
  });

}

const dummy = 'https://dummyimage.com/48x48/633a63/000000.png&text=n/a';

const imgs = [
  { name: 'flower', src: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1649922694096-35448dfd411f' },
  { name: 'badImage', src: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1649922694096-35448dfd411eeeddddd'  },
  { name: 'sign', src: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1649928210166-52c1b1d8279e' }
];

function filterImages(data) {
  return data.map(async obj => {
    const exists = await checkIfImageExists(obj.src);
    if (exists) return obj;
    return { ...obj, src: dummy };
  });
}

async function main() {
  console.log('Waiting for the image-checking to complete...');
  const filtered = await Promise.all(filterImages(imgs));
  console.log(filtered);
}

main();
```